# Can I find the length of a post post-rendering?

Tags: support, data-explorer, character-limit, answer-length

I can find the length of the post's HTML-converted source (`len(Posts.body)`) in data.SE.

Is there a way — short of copy/pasting from actual SE page — to find out the textual length of the rendered post, sans markup? Preferably via data.SE.

Comment: Actually Posts.Body is the HTML rendered version of the text. To find the Markdown version of the text, you have to look in PostHistory.

Comment: @animuson - "post-rendering" also meant post-HTML rendering. What I get if I copy-paste from actual SE page.

Comment: Not unless you want to write an HTML parser in SQL. Which is a worse idea than [writing an HTML parser in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4751173).

Comment: Wouldn't the length depend on the browser setting?

Comment: Rene posted the answer for that as a comment under my answer to your question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297954/why-is-lenposts-body-incorrect-on-answers-in-data-se. Maybe he'll post it here as an answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be a duplicate of that other question you asked? They are not that much different?

Comment: @rene Well, the other question asks what `LEN(Body)` is and this question asks how to get he markdown length of `Body`. Is like a usual follow up question. So I don't think that this question is a suitable dupe of the other one.

Comment: @Tom it so closely related, if I answer this I mainly copy your answer and replace your query with mine. It feels ... inefficient  ...

Comment: @rene well, that's true :/. I wonder if it would be ok if you edit your part into my answer and then close it as a dupe. But that also looks a bit like manipulation (edit/enhance an answer to also answer a similar question). I wonder what the correct behaviour would be.

Comment: @Tom - see edit please

Comment: I'm still; confused what number you're looking for. Let's take the example of your scifi [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114611). If I open up the dev console of Chrome and run `$('#answer-114611 .post-text').html().trim().length` the result is 36387. That are the number of characters in the html DOM for that answe in the SE page  which is one less then what you find from `len(posts.body)`. I'm not clear what post-rendering means for you. Do you mean you want to know upfront based on a given markdown what the length of the actual content in the SE page will be?

Comment: @rene - in crude terms, the # of printed characters in actual HTML page. Load SE answer into Chrome, select entire answer, Copy, paste into editor, count characters. NOT HTML source, the actual rendered page.

Comment: for that scifi answer it would be 6431 characters. Is that about right?

Comment: @rene - I get 6636 but yes

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere. And you want to get that number as a result when you query in SEDE for a couple of posts?

Comment: Still wondering why you have 6636. I have [this](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/d92d56ae5e4059638f8a265a92d304b2) as the answer text and that is 6476 chars.